# AudioFileIO leaves inputstream opened after giving log warn "No space to find another frame"

Tags: java, audio, mp3, inputstream, jaudiotagger

I am attempting to read a files audio length in Java using the following code:

`return AudioFileIO.read(new File(audio)).getAudioHeader().getTrackLength() * 1000;`

This works and gives me (roughly) the length of the audio file, but leaves an inputstream open, meaning that later on I cant delete the files, atleast not during runtime.
This is problematic because Im using temporary files here and the directory needs to be cleared.

This is the output I get in my console:

```
Mai 06, 2023 10:30:13 PM org.jaudiotagger.tag.id3.AbstractID3v2Frame readIdentifier
WARNING: tmp0.mp3:No space to find another frame:
Mai 06, 2023 10:30:13 PM org.jaudiotagger.tag.id3.ID3v24Tag readFrames
WARNING: tmp0.mp3:Invalid Frame:tmp0.mp3:No space to find another frame
Mai 06, 2023 10:30:13 PM org.jaudiotagger.audio.mp3.MP3File readV2Tag
SEVERE: Could not invoke DirectBuffer method - illegal access`
```

This is the files metadata, according to (https://www.checkfiletype.com):

```
File Size   36 kB
File Type   MP3
File Type Extension mp3
MIME Type   audio/mpeg
ID3 Size    45
MPEG Audio Version  2
Audio Layer 3
Audio Bitrate   128 kbps
Sample Rate 24000
Channel Mode    Single Channel
MS Stereo   Off
Intensity Stereo    Off
Copyright Flag  False
Original Media  True
Emphasis    None
Encoder Settings    Lavf58.76.100
Duration    2.30 s (approx)
```

I cant entirely seem to understand what the problem is thats making it throw that warning. Is the metadata faulty? If so, what can I do to fix it? Im getting the .mp3 through an API.
Is there a different class I could use? The AudioSystem/AudioInputStream classes didnt work either and threw an error, saying the file type is unsupported.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed by increasing the maven depdendency from 2.2.5 to version 3.0.1:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.jthink</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaudiotagger</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```